# How do I launch a DialogFragment from a string test on an EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-dialogfragment

I'm looking to show a dialog from a dialogfragment if the user presses the Back button and there is user-typed input on an EditText line.  I don't want to launch the dialogfragment automatically in the activity file.  I want to launch it based on the string test in the EditText file ("BackButton.java").

CardActivity.java file:

```
public class CardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cardviewinput);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    CreateFragment createFragment = new CreateFragment();
    createFragment.show(fm, "card_dialog");
...
```

BackButton.java file:

```
public class OnBackCard extends EditText {

... 
}

public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, @NonNull KeyEvent event) {
    this.keyCode = keyCode;
    this.event = event;
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {

            getKeyDispatcherState().startTracking(event, this);
            return true;
        }

        else if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            getKeyDispatcherState().handleUpEvent(event);
            if (event.isTracking() && !event.isCanceled()) {
        final EditText ToDoEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CEditText);
        int stringToDo = ToDoEditText.getText().toString().trim().length();
        // Test the data input line for any user input data
     if(stringToDo>0) {
         // This is where I'm looking for code to launch the dialog and
         // the next lines close the soft keyboard 
         InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
               context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
         imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.getWindowToken(), 0);
     return false;
```

CreateFragment.java file:

```
public class CreateFragment extends DialogFragment {

public CreateFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.skyfrag_layout, container, false);
getDialog().setTitle("Delete card");
...
return rootView;
...
```

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question. What prevents you from doing what you want to do?

Comment: The code above automatically pops open the dialog on top of the CardActivity UI.  I want to have the code test for user input on the EditText line on the CardActivity layout.  Only if there is user input data that has been typed in, then launch the dialog.

Comment: So what prevents you from checking if there is user input in the edit text, inside the onBackPressed() function?

Comment: he is trying to say why dont you just show it like you did the first time like this `createFragment.show(fm, "card_dialog");`

Comment: I edited the BackButton file to show the full extent of the BackButton code.  So I am not using the onBackPressed() function.  I have the string test working correctly, I just need to be able to tell the activity file to launch the dialog based on the string test indicating there is data present.  As of right now, the dialog just launches automatically because the activity file doesn't know anything about the EditText string test in the BackButton file.